# Screwturn to connect to a DB on another server

Tags: wiki, screwturn

The wiki runs perfectly on the local sql-express instance. I have installed SQL enterprise on a remote server, same network, yet still the connection string which should be simple to build is not working properly.

anyone has hit the same boulder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was with the sa password of the db

when installing the db make sure to select mixed modes so as to have an sa password.